# How to export and import dotnet dev-certs correctly?

Tags: .net, ssl, .net-core, https

I tried to create, export and then import `.NET 7 developer certificates` but it seems this does not work in a straightforward way. So, it occurred to me to turn to a collective brain.

Here is what I did

1. `dotnet dev-certs https --trust --check`

> [No valid cerficicate found.]

2. `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

> Successfully created and trusted a new HTTPS certificate.

At this point I can check with `certmgr.msc` that there's a certificate in "My"/CurrentUser (pfx) and the same one in "Root"/LocalMachine (cer).

Then if I

3. `dotnet dev-certs --clean`

> HTTPS development certificates successfully removed from the machine.

4. `dotnet dev-certs https --trust --check`

> No valid cerficicate found.]

Now, if I use `certmgr.msc` to import the certificates again and then

5. `dotnet dev-certs https --trust --check`

> No valid cerficicate found.

This feels very unexpected, I would assume there is a trusted certificate in place.

It's the same situation even if I do `dotnet dev-certs https --export-path "dev-cert.pfx --password "somepassword"` and then try to import this certificate.

What I actually tried to do initially was to set a developer certificate in Azure DevOps. But it so happens `dotnet dev-certs --trust` requires an interactive prompt by the Windows Server OS and so won't work. Hence trying to just import a certificate created elsewhere.

I also tried to consume the pfx certificate via [appsettings.json:Kestrel:HttpsInlineCertFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-7.0) does not seem to work. So it looks like there's something either with export or re-import of a certificate created with `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`, but can't put a finger into it.